# How to handle performence issue in android(AOSP) device

Tags: android, performance, rendering, android-source

Cuttlefish Android launched in Linux OS based device.

- Getting around 4 min to launch android home screen in cuttlefish screen.
- Rendering is too slow
- Keep on getting "system UI isn't responding" message
- Applications are freezing.
  Could you please help me , how to resolve this issue.Please let me know if you have any suggestions to understand this issue.

please find below lolcat logs.

```
   06-12 17:25:56.967  1937  1937 D DN-100-C: ConnectedState: updateNetworkCapabilities: Capabilities not changed.
   06-12 17:25:59.100   635  1593 D ActivityManager: freezing 2769 com.android.traceur
   06-12 17:25:59.101   635  1593 I am_freeze: [2769,com.android.traceur]
   06-12 17:26:01.013   476   568 D AT      : AT< +CSQ: 99,99,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,99,107,2147483647,2147483647,2147483647,2147483647,2147483647,99,99,2147483647,2147483647,2147483647,2147483647,2147483647,2147483647
   06-12 17:26:01.235  3303  3313 I ndroid.systemui: Background concurrent copying GC freed 140838(6216KB) AllocSpace objects, 110(2200KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 12MB/24MB, paused 190us,106us total 202.793ms
   06-12 17:26:01.799   635  1593 D ActivityManager: freezing 2841 com.android.calendar
   06-12 17:26:01.801   635  1593 I am_freeze: [2841,com.android.calendar]
   06-12 17:26:01.843   635  1593 D ActivityManager: freezing 2864 com.android.camera2
   06-12 17:26:01.844   635  1593 I am_freeze: [2864,com.android.camera2]
   06-12 17:26:03.876   635  1593 D ActivityManager: freezing 2908 com.android.contacts
   06-12 17:26:03.877   635  1593 I am_freeze: [2908,com.android.contacts]
   06-12 17:26:04.400   635  1593 D ActivityManager: freezing 2295 com.android.documentsui
   06-12 17:26:04.401   635  1593 I am_freeze: [2295,com.android.documentsui]
   06-12 17:26:05.182   635  1593 D ActivityManager: freezing 2192 com.android.deskclock
   06-12 17:26:05.183   635  1593 I am_freeze: [2192,com.android.deskclock]
   06-12 17:26:07.751   635  1593 D ActivityManager: freezing 3171 com.android.carrierconfig
   06-12 17:26:07.753   635  1593 I am_freeze: [3171,com.android.carrierconfig]
   06-12 17:26:08.504   635  1593 D ActivityManager: freezing 2981 com.android.messaging
   06-12 17:26:08.506   635  1593 I am_freeze: [2981,com.android.messaging]
   06-12 17:26:08.660   635  1593 D ActivityManager: freezing 3005 com.android.imsserviceentitlement
   06-12 17:26:08.661   635  1593 I am_freeze: [3005,com.android.imsserviceentitlement]
   06-12 17:26:09.823   635  1593 D ActivityManager: freezing 2880 com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver.module
   06-12 17:26:09.824   635  1593 I am_freeze: [2880,com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver.module]
   06-12 17:26:11.013   476   568 D AT      : AT< +CSQ: 99,99,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,99,112,2147483647,2147483647,2147483647,2147483647,2147483647,99,99,2147483647,2147483647,2147483647,2147483647,2147483647,2147483647
```